# Error Referencing Externally loaded SWF

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm loading an swf say "test.swf" which gets loaded in imageLoader , so I can get its content by :

```
imageLoader.content
```

So if I wanted one of the movieClips inside it I would do this :

```
imageLoader.content.testMovie.transform.colorTransform = someTransformation;
```

But when I do this, since the movie is not loaded the file is not compiled and gives me an error your referring to something that is not there. How else am I supposed to reference a content that will be loaded later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait till it is loaded. Listen to its `complete` event and access content from there.

```
imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  MovieClip(imageLoader.content).testMovie.transform.colorTransform = someTransformation;
}
```

If `testMovie` is yet another dynamically loaded SWF, wait till it is loaded - listen to the `complete` event dispatched by `testMovie.contentLoaderInfo`.

Even better, if you have access to the loaded SWF, dispatch a custom event from there when `testMovie` is loaded and listen to it from the main SWF.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference something that hasn't loaded. 
If you want to apply a transform you can do that on the parent clip but this might not be what you are after.