# as3 access an object inside a loaded swf

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have two swf, one loads the other using a Loader class, in the loaded swf I have a NetConnection object which I need to access from the host swf, but I can't, if I debug the app, I see the obejct is there, but I can't access it, if I try to set a variable like

loadedSWF = connectorLoader.content (connectorLoader is the Loader object)

loadedSWF is always null

If I debig the app, I see the NetConnection in the loaded SWF, but I can't have access to it, I have try to use Security.allowDomain("*") in both swf to be sure, but nothing, I thought that only doing the allowDomain method I will have access to the loaded SWF objects

I'm usign Flas Player version 10.1

thanks! for any help

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `loadedSWF = connectorLoader.content;` from the complete event handler? If not read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408527/error-referencing-externally-loaded-swf/2408957#2408957)

Answer (score 0):

That said I would make sure that your loaded swf is a debug swf?  Do you have the source code for the debug swf?  In Flash Builder when specifying external libraries, you have to specify the source code location.  How do you expect the Flex Debugger to be aware of the source code location for an asset loaded at runtime?

I don't think it was possible to debug through loaded assets.

Comment: thanks for the reply, well the debug test I made was only for testing and to ensure the object is there, but I'm trying to load the host swf from domainA.com and inside there load other swf from domainB.com without any debugging, but I'm NOT able to access the object in swf loaded from domainB.com, even if I use Security.allowDomain("*") in the loaded swf from domainB.com, thanks for any help